# How to avoid object wrapper inside object in jackson

Tags: java, json, mongodb, hibernate-ogm, jackson2

I was new to the **spring restful with Jackson and Hibernate OGM**. I'm getting JSON format as below from web request

```
"Order": 
{ 
  "Orderdata": [ {"orderNo" : "1","location":"A"},{"orderNo" : "2","location":"B"},..]
}
```

Pojo class for order

```
class Order implements Serializable{
@ElementCollection
private List<OrderData> Orderdata = null;

//getter and setter
}
```

After inserting the document into MongoDB. I'm getting as below

```
"Order": {
  "Orderdata": [
    {
      "Orderdata": {"orderNo" : "1","location":"A"}
    },
    {
      "Orderdata": {"orderNo" : "2","location":"B"}
    },
    ...
  ]}
```

Here I need to avoid the **"Orderdata" name inside the each document** created. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please post the POJO class for OrderData also

Comment: @Embeddable
class OrderData implements Serializable{ private String orderNo; private String location;
//getter and setter
}

Comment: Which version of Hibernate OGM are you using? That doesn;'t seem that way it shoudl be mapped on MongoDB. I can only have to explanations for it: you  found a bug or some other library on top of OGM is causing the issue. Do you think you could create a test case or a project that I can check to replicate the issue?

Comment: I'm using hibernate-ogm 5.0.0 version. Yes, it's inserting with object name in the member variable on pojo class and I'm creating project.